# URI Used to Create ZipFileSystem Having A Square Bracket Gives Error in Java, How to Get Past This?

Tags: java, filesystems, uri, zip

Path String in question:

```
"F:\oobar\Foobar\FoobarFoo\barFo\obarFoob\Fo [oba rFoobarFoo] - barF oobar.cbz"
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 52: file:/F:/oobar/Foobar/FoobarFoo/barFo/obarFoob/Fo [oba rFoobarFoo] - barF oobar.cbz
```

Code:

```
    URI zipDisk = URI.create("jar:file:/" + comic.toString().replace("\\", "/").replace(" ", "%20"));
    //URI zipDisk = comic.toURI();

    Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
    zipProperties.put("create", "true");

    try(FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipDisk, zipProperties)) //Error on this line
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
```

What can I do to get past this error? Changing the path is not an option as it is essential that my folder structure does not change. Thanks in advance for any and all help regarding the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have just discovered, converting a file name to a URI is not as simple as replacing the file separator and replacing any space characters.  There are many characters which are not allowed in a URI.

You were on the right track when you tried using `comic.toURI()`.  That is, in fact, the only correct way to convert a `File` to a URI:

```
URI zipDisk = URI.create("jar:" + comic.toURI());
```

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick!

Might I ask what the "jar:" and "file:/" prefixes are? Because when I had it as "jar:file:/"; basically the code in my original post ran fine so long as there weren't any illegal characters...

Comment: `file:` is the *scheme* (also known as the protocol) of a file URI.  There are other schemes, like “http:” and “https:”.  A jar: URI actually consists of the `jar:` scheme followed by another URI (optionally followed by the name of an entry in the jar, but that doesn’t apply when specifying a zip file system), as described in the [zip file system documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).  Schemes, and the format of URIs in general, are described in [RFC 2396](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396).